# make: *** No rule to make target `my_project.o', needed by `objects'. Stop

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my makefile in linux

```
.SILENT:
.SUFFIXES: .cpp

FLAGS_CC      = -c -fPIC -DUNIX -DLINUX -D_HNAREL_=500 -D_TARGET__REL=0 -D_TARGET__DEBUG=1 -D_ILS_MACROS -I$(cer_incl)
FLAGS_CPP     = -c -Wno-deprecated -fPIC -frtti -finline-functions -DUNIX -DLINUX -D_HNAREL_=500 -D_TARGET__REL=0 -D_TARGET__DEBUG=1 -D_ILS_MACROS -I$(cer_incl)
FLAGS_LINK    = -m32 -fPIC -lm -lc -lrt -lpthread -ldl
FLAGS_LINKSHR = -m32 -lm -lc -shared -Wl,-no-undefined -lrt -lpthread -ldl

CC      = gcc $(FLAGS_CC) $(__define) $(__build)
CPP     = g++ $(FLAGS_CPP) $(__define) $(__build)
LINK    = g++ $(FLAGS_LINK)
LINKSHR = g++ $(FLAGS_LINKSHR)
PRINT   = echo

##
## The following environment variables are defined for your convenience.
##-----
## __srcdir - Project directory that contains the makefile and source code.
## __objdir - Project subdirectory that stores objects for the given platform
##            and target combination.
## __libdir - Public directory that contains objects and shareable libraries.
## __exedir - Public directory that contains executables.
##-----
## Please do not delete the following line!
###makefile###
###makedep###

#my_project.o
FLAGS__MY_PROJECT =
DEFINES__MY_PROJECT =
my_project.o: $(__objdir)/my_project.o
$(__objdir)/my_project.o: \
   my_project.cpp \
   $(cer_incl)/srvimpl.h \
  
    $(PRINT) "compiling - my_project.cpp"
    [[ -d $(__objdir) ]] || mkdir -p $(__objdir)
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS__MY_PROJECT) $(DEFINES__MY_PROJECT) -o $(__objdir)/my_project.o my_project.cpp

#aps_s200061.o
FLAGS__APS_S200061 =
DEFINES__APS_S200061 =
aps_s200061.o: $(__objdir)/aps_s200061.o
$(__objdir)/aps_s200061.o: \
   aps_s200061.cpp \
   aps_s200061.h \
   $(cer_incl)/srvimpl.h \
   
    $(PRINT) "compiling - aps_s200061.cpp"
    [[ -d $(__objdir) ]] || mkdir -p $(__objdir)
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS__APS_S200061) $(DEFINES__APS_S200061) -o $(__objdir)/aps_s200061.o aps_s200061.cpp

###makedep###

FLAGS_CPP += -D__RHEL6

FLAGS__APS_S200061 =

objects: my_project.o aps_s200061.o 

my_project : objects
    $(PRINT) "creating - my_project "
    $(LINKSHR) \
        -Wl,--version-script=$(__srcdir)/my_project.emap \
        -o $(__objdir)/my_project \
        $(__objdir)/my_project.o \
        $(__objdir)/aps_s200061.o \
    -Wl,--start-group \
        -L$(__libdir) -lapsobj -lcernobj -lcontainerobj -lstringobj -li18n_common -lmsgutilobj -lmftmiscobj -lsrvcoreobj -lcrmobj -lthreadobj \
            -Wl,--whole-archive -lsrvobj -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
    -Wl,--end-group \
        -L$(__exedir) -ldb -ldps -lsrv -lsec \
             -lcclora -lreg -lmsgapi -ldate \
             -llogical -lsrvcore -lcrm

copy:
    $(PRINT) "copying - my_project"
    cp $(__objdir)/my_project $(__exedir)

it: my_project copy

# shr:my_project
```

I want to remove the command cp $(__objdir)/my_project $(__exedir) from the above file.
When I try removing the line manually in a text editor and save it , the make file doesn't throw any errors.

But if I try removing the line programmatically ,  we get make: *** No rule to make target `my_project.o', needed by` objects'.  Stop.

Sequence of commands we use is :
'makedep'
'make -f ${PWD##*/}.linux -r __target=rel _*define="-D_TARGET*=_TARGET__REL " __srcdir=$PWD __objdir=$PWD/linuxx86-64 __libdir=$abc_lib_rel __exedir=$abc_exe_rel __build="-O3" it'

Comment: "removing the line programmatically" -- seems like there is your error. What are the differences between doing this manually and programmatically?

Comment: I have to do that modification across many projects. So I have a python script which will parse through each makefile of all those projects and make the modification.

Comment: You know that tabs/spaces make a significant difference in makefiles and that they are a common cause of issues? That said, maybe that tool is the problem. However, your question doesn't provide enough info by far! Please extract and provide a [mcve], though I guess you'll find the issue yourself doing so. As a relatively new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].